# How can I change a reference to an owned value without clone?

Tags: rust

I'm practicing Rust concepts that I've learned while reading The Book.  I've been able to iterate over my `List` enum by copying the `Box` and assigning the `list` to the copied box, but intuitively, I feel like there must be a way to just "make it point to the next pointer in line".

If I attempt to do this without `bx.clone()`, like so: `self.list = **bx`, I get  "cannot move out of `**bx` which is behind a mutable reference."  Which means that I need it to be owned, but I can't get an owned `bx` because I need to move it as a reference when I dereference it in the `if let`.

Is it possible or advisable to move the reference without copying it?

```
#[derive(Clone)]
enum List {
    Cons(u32, Box<List>),
    Nil,
}
struct ListHolder {
    list: List,
}

impl Iterator for ListHolder {
    type Item = u32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        if let Cons(num, bx) = &mut self.list {
            let val = *num;
            self.list = *bx.clone(); // This is the key line
            Some(val)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

use List::*;

fn main() {
    let list_inst = ListHolder {
        list: Cons(1, Box::new(Cons(2, Box::new(Cons(3, Box::new(Nil)))))),
    };
    for i in list_inst.into_iter() {
        println!("{}", i); // Prints 1, 2, 3 as expected
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear "for anyone writing a Rust program. 99% of the time you should just use a Vec (array stack), and 99% of the other 1% of the time you should be using a VecDeque (array deque)." see https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/. Rust is not at all a lang design for linked list.

Comment: Mandatory link: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: There are many solutions, depending on the underlying problem, for example using Rc references, or indexes related to a managed buffer (see the id-arena crate for example).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the key issue with your mental model is that you're thinking of `Box<T>` as simply a pointer. Rust references (and most smart pointers like `Box<T>`) are not merely pointers, but *valid* pointers. That is, there are no null references and references must always point to valid data at all times.

When we try to do `self.list = **bx;`, we're moving the data from `bx` to `self.list`. However, `bx` doesn't own its data. When the mutable borrow `bx` ends, the actual owner is going to be holding invalid data.

So what do we do? The simplest way is what's sometimes called [Jones' Trick](https://matklad.github.io/2019/07/25/unsafe-as-a-type-system.html) where we switch out the data in `bx` for some dummy value. Now the actual owner of the data in `bx` won't be holding invalid data. So how do we do this? This is the purview of the function `std::mem::replace` which takes a mutable reference and a value and replaces the data behind the mutable reference with that value, returning what was behind the mutable reference before (including ownership!). That's exactly what we want to do here with `self.list = std::mem::replace(&mut **bx, List::Nil)`. Again, `List::Nil` is just some dummy data; any `List` at all would work exactly the same.

```
enum List {
    Cons(u32, Box<List>),
    Nil,
}
struct ListHolder {
    list: List,
}

impl Iterator for ListHolder {
    type Item = u32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        if let Cons(num, bx) = &mut self.list {
            let val = *num;
            self.list = std::mem::replace(&mut **bx, List::Nil); // This is the key line
            Some(val)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

use List::*;

fn main() {
    let list_inst = ListHolder {
        list: Cons(1, Box::new(Cons(2, Box::new(Cons(3, Box::new(Nil)))))),
    };
    for i in list_inst.into_iter() {
        println!("{}", i); // Prints 1, 2, 3 as expected
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=12c42b6230331a03686fbf401b0903eb)

To be slightly more idiomatic, instead of `&mut **bx`, we could simply use `bx.as_mut()` to get a mutable reference from the box. Also, the `into_iter` call on `list_inst` is unnecessary since `ListHolder` already implements `Iterator` so it doesn't need to be turned into one. You may also be wondering about `num` and `val` and why we still have to make a temporary variable for that.

The reason is that this value is still just a reference and we don't have owned access to the owner (`self.list`). That means we have to make a copy of it to return. `u32` implements `Copy` so this isn't really a problem, but if you tried to make the linked list generic in the type of its elements, it simply wouldn't work. `let val = *num;` is the same kind of "moving out of borrowed content" that we couldn't do before.

The solution is to use `std::mem::replace` to get ownership not just of the data behind `bx`, but of the whole list. So if we use `std::mem::replace(&mut self.list, List::Nil)` before destructuring, `self.list` will be replaced with a dummy value and we'll have ownership of the actual list, including both the value and the tail of the list. This also means that we can just have `self.list = *bx`, as I'm sure you originally wanted.

```
impl Iterator for ListHolder {
    type Item = u32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        if let Cons(num, bx) = std::mem::replace(&mut self.list, List::Nil) {
            self.list = *bx;
            Some(num)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=277bbeeffb60455ffd154113da435133)

The upshot is now you can [make the list generic](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=49cb71268838212b88ca1b3e687b47a0) with hardly any effort.

If you want to learn more about how Rust's ownership model affects the implementation of linked lists, you can do no better than the excellent series [*Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/). The series covers everything here in detail as well as many variations.