# Taking ownership of HashMap.get() result without cloning

Tags: rust

Is there a more efficient way of getting an owned value from a HashMap than this line?

```
let output_items = output_tables.get(TABLE_NAME_TLIST).unwrap().to_owned();
```

This screenshot expands the types:

[image: code snippet]

- relates to [Rust - Change a reference to own value without clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254329/rust-change-a-reference-to-own-value-without-clone)

Comment: Do you want to take from the HashMap?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to take ownership of the value, `HashMap::remove()` will return an `Option<T>` rather than the `Option<&T>` returned by `HashMap::get()`. See [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3324989ae331c30f3c3790a3ef6c06cb):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(1, "a");
    assert_eq!(map.remove(&1), Some("a"));
    assert_eq!(map.remove(&1), None);
}
```

If you want the value to remain in the `HashMap` but also own the value elsewhere, you can wrap it in an `Rc<T>` to share ownership. If the object needs to be mutable, you can wrap it in an `Rc<RefCell<T>>`.

Comment: Thanks. This really reinforces the idea of "ownership". Coming for Python world, I didn't think of removing and taking ownership to be so close in semantics.